# Python <function at 0x> output

Tags: python, python-3.x, runtime-error

I wrote a new function and when I execute it, I get an error:

`<function read_grades at 0x000001F69E0FC8C8>`

Ok so here is my code:

```
def add(x, y):
    z = x / y * 100
    return z

def calc_grade(perc):
    if perc < 50:
        return "1"
    if perc <  60:
        return "2"
    if perc < 75:
        return "3"
    if perc < 90:
        return "4"
    if perc >= 90:
        return "5"

def calc_command():
    num1 = input("Input your points: ")
    num2 = input("Input maximum points: ")
    num3 = add(float(num1), float(num2))
    grade = calc_grade(num3)
    print("This is your result:", str(num3) + "%")
    print("Your grade:", grade)
    save = open("grades.txt", "r")
    read_grades = save.read()
    save = open("grades.txt", "w")
    save.write(read_grades + grade)
    save.close()

def read_grades():
    save = open("grades.txt", "r")
    read_grades = save.read()
    grades = read_grades.split()
    save.close()
    return grades

while True:
    command = input("Input your command: ")
    if command == "CALC":
        calc_command()
    elif command == "EXIT":
        break
    elif command == "GRADES":
        print(read_grades)
    elif command == "HELP":
        print("These are the commands:\nCALC - Calculates your grade and writes in the file.\nEXIT - Exits the program.\nGRADES - Reads your previous grades.\nHELP - This command. It helps you.")
    else:
        print("You inputed an invalid command. Type HELP for help.")
```

This error happens when I execute the read_grades() function or the GRADES command.

For those who marked this question: I did some searching and I didn't find that post and now that i read it i dont understand the answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's not a runtime error, you printed a function

```
print(read_grades)
```

Try calling it instead

```
read_grades()
```

And you override your function here

```
read_grades = save.read()
```

So, advice is to not use variable names that conflict with your function names

Comment: Yeah i had to change return to print but THANK YOU SO MUCH and another question how do you seperate a string with no spaces into a string with comas and spaces or an array?

Comment: @1234filip That question about splitting a string has got nothing to do with the current question! If you can't find an answer after _thorough_ searching, ask a new question, but you'll need to explain it better than that, and illustrate it with some typical input and expected output.

Comment: Ok I will search the internet kk

Comment: You may ask a new question using the button at the top of the page. `split()` takes a string parameter, though. The default is to split on whitespace. You can create a string from a list using `str.join()`